# Recaptcha throws Invalid Domain if put in nested iFrame / iFrame inception

Tags: iframe, recaptcha

I have a page (page A) that have a popup/modal (page B) for users to input something. The Page B must be rendered by iframe since Page B has its own styling. I would like to put the google reCAPTCHA on the page B to let user verify before input anything.

If I only check Page B, the reCAPTCHA works fine. If page A render page B not using iframe, the reCAPTCHA works fine (but page B is messed up with jQuery conflicts). But, if Page A renders Page B using iFrame, the reCAPTCHA shows

```
ERROR for site owner:
Invalid domain for site key
```

This belongs to nested iFrame but what if we have no control of the inner iFrame? Is there any solution to use reCAPTCHA in page B? All ideas appreciated!